# How do I safely upgrade from server 16.04 to 20.04?

Tags: 16.04, server, 20.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

As said in the title. Specifically, I want to loose nothing, neither Systemd services, cron jobs, files in my \home folder, config... If upgrading means risking loosing one of these, then I won't upgrade.

So is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading). If have heavily customized or haywired your system, then breakage and loss is more likely. Best practice is generally to return your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible before release-upgrading...since that's what we tested. Backups are wise before you begin. Something not backed up is something you are willing to lose.

Comment: Either way you have to upgrade, because 16.04 will be end-of-support in one month: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: The tested paths of upgrade from 16.04 were to 16.10 (ie. next release, but that path is gone due to 16.10 being EOL), or to 18.04 (the next LTS release).  All other paths don't receive full testing, getting only *machine-testing* (package-rule tested) as for issues and issues matter less as it's not a *fully tested* or *fully-supported* tested path.  The only fully-supported path from 16.04 currently is to 18.04 (not jumping releases; any testing on that path is on you as it's not an intended path).

Comment: Upgrade documentation for 16.04 can be read at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/18.04.1